# Can resource directory be a subdirectory of sources in maven?

Tags: java, maven, resources

I am trying to create a maven build for one of our legacy projects. Since one of the requirements is to be still compatible with the legacy ant build script I can't change the project directory structure.

The problem is the current directory structure which is as follows:

```
+ src
  + java
    + com
      + whatever
        + whatever2
          + resources (!)
```

My goal is to have source directory `src/java` and resource directory `src/java/com/whatever/whatever2/resources`.

Obviously I need to set `<sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>`. This is fine.

But I would also need to make the `resources` maven resource directory. Trying the following:

```
    <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/java/com/whatever/whatever2/resources</directory>
       </resource>
    </resources>
```

But once I do this and run `mvn clean package` it gives me:

```
[INFO] No sources to compile
```

Once I remove the `<resources>` section the module is compiled just fine and have all the classes inside. Any tips on how to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a similar setup (XMBean descriptors next to the MBean implementations using them), but exclude java files from the resources:

```
<resource>
  <directory>src/main/java</directory>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
  </excludes>
</resource>
```

Comment: @Jan I'm not entirely sure but I guess that Maven keeps a list of already processed files and since the .java files would be already processed by the resources plugin when not excluded, the compiler plugin might ignore them.